# How can I add my email address to the dictionary?

Tags: apps, dictionary

It would be good to be able to add words & phrases to the dictionary e.g. my email address (which I am having to input a lot)

I know you can add a word if it gets a red squiggle and a + sign, but this option doesn't show up against an email address perhaps because of the punctuation.

**Edit**
As a while has passed since this question, I wondered if the situation has changed with any of the phone updates? Or is there an app which will do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My technique for this is that I teach the dictionary the part of my email that's before the @ symbol. So everytime I need to enter my email address, text prediction shows me my email name after about 2 key presses.

Yeah, you then have to enter @yourDomain.com, but I find this much faster than nothing.

Answer (score 4):

The text prediction only works for single words, and because email address have punctuation in them (essentially multiple words) the phone will not recognize it.

What I have done is similar to what Lance said. I added my "name" part of the email to the dictionary, and also the domain. Sorry, but this is about the best you are going to be able to get. Perhaps in the future we will be able to add multi-word phrases.

Answer (score -2):

Open the messaging app, and then open any random thread. Type your email address, then if squiggly lines appear, add them. This should work just fine.

Comment: If you email had any "_" or "." It won't work even for the first part. After you type the "@" the dictionary will stop its prediction. Wrong answer.